# How to use jni.h for Android?

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I want to call Java codes included `Android SDK` classes from C++. I can call pure Java codes from C++ for `desktop console application`. But I cannot call Java codes included `Android SDK` classes from C++ for Android (I get this error: `JNI_CreateJavaVM was not declared in this scope.`). I want an example for `Java Native Interface` for Android. Have you got examples about JNI for Android? Also, I found JNI examples and codes for desktop only, no Android.
Also I found different `jni.h` and `libjvm.so` files positions:

```
jni.h Directories: ------------------------------------

/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/include/jni.h
Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-*/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h
android-studio/jre/include/jni.h

libjvm.so Directories: --------------------------------

/home/username/android-studio/jre/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
```

Answer (score 2):

To explain it simple, if you want to call a Java function from C++, you should implement a jni Callback.

You could follow the hello-jniCallback project from this [android ndk examples repository](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk).

Most of the examples are written in C rather than in C++, so you should do some changes.
For example those functions in C like:

`FindClass(env, someString)`

In C++ you should use:

`env->FindClass(someString)`

Comment: Thanks, I don't use `Android Studio`. I use `Qt`. Do I use this examples for `Qt`? I know `QtAndroidExtras` for Qt. But I have to use pure jni.

Comment: I have never used Qt to develop Android applications. Do you use gradle to configure your porject?

Comment: Yes, Qt provides a `build.gradle` file. ([Like This](https://s24.postimg.org/55tifomtx/img.png)).

Comment: Then, How are you compiling the cpp code? Using the build.gradle or you are compiling it by yourself using `make` cmd?

Comment: [My Cpp Code](https://s27.postimg.org/6cdhkomcj/image.png) and [My Java Code](https://s23.postimg.org/gs0l4414r/image.png)

Comment: Also, I asked a question for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41556843/how-can-i-run-java-codes-in-qt-c-without-qandroidextras

Comment: Please check the sources from [hello-jniCallback project](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/hello-jniCallback). You are highly likely to find the solution to your problem.